# complete data og left table other then join connection

Tags: mysql, left-join, preserve

my left table data is "Message"

```
id     advid      seller_id     purchase _id      delete_status

15      93           28            19                 yes
22      134          34            19                 yes
25      168          15            19                 No
17      130          19            2                  yes
24      134          34            6                  No
```

my right table data is "DeleteMessage"

```
id   addid      sessionid     messageid      
1      93          19           15
2      134         34           22
3      93          28           15
4      130         19           17
```

i am inserting advid , id and the active person(seller/purchaser) as sessionid in deleteTable

Now i want data from message table  whose seller/purchase id is not enterd as session id in delete table

i am using left join but its is not preserving my data from left table

my query is

```
select * from message
left join deletetable
on message.id = deletetable.messageid
where sessionid !='34'
AND (purchase_id='34' OR seller_id='34')
```

according to my wish this query should gives me entry no 24 of message table  but nothing is showing up

Comment: no it is giving me all entries of 34 from left table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS message;

CREATE TABLE message
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,seller_id INT NOT NULL
,purchase_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO message VALUES
(15,28,19),
(22,34,19),
(25,15,19),
(17,19,2),
(24,34,6);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deletemessage;

CREATE TABLE deletemessage
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,sessionid INT NOT NULL
,messageid INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO deletemessage VALUES
(1,19,15),
(2,34,22),
(3,28,15),
(4,19,17);

SELECT x.* 
  FROM message x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN deletemessage y 
    ON y.messageid = x.id 
   AND y.sessionid = 34 
 WHERE 34 IN (x.seller_id,x.purchase_id) 
   AND y.id IS NULL;
+----+-----------+-------------+
| id | seller_id | purchase_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+
| 24 |        34 |           6 |
+----+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've read your question correctly, but this looks to give the result you're asking for:

```
SELECT m.id, m.advid, m.seller_id, m.purchase_id, m.delete_status 
  FROM message m
LEFT JOIN deletetable d ON m.id = d.messageid 
WHERE d.messageid IS NULL
AND (purchase_id = '34' OR seller_id = '34')
```

This retrieves all values from `message` that don't have an entry in `deletetable` and also where the `seller_id` or `purchase_id` is '34'

Result from your sample using the above:

```
| *id* | *advid* | *seller_id* | *purchase_id* | *delete_status* |
+------+---------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 24   | 134     | 34          | 6             | No              |
```

**Note:** You've surrounded your `purchase_id` and `seller_id` in apostrophes, i.e. '34', so I have assumed this is a String field rather than Integer.  If it is an Integer field, you can remove them - they're not necessary and it makes the query a little slower.

Comment: I can't see the session id here